# Properly using a Gamow Bag

Tags: gear, safety, mountaineering, high-altitude

I was just informed that our group is going to have a Gam-off, technically known as a [Gamow Bag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamow_bag).

While I have never seen one such thing and so I don't have any experience with them, I browsed the internet about it for a while. 
A few questions:

- Do they have a high-altitude operating ranges like sleeping bags have?
- How much do they cost?
- How much do they weight?
- Is it okay to drag someone off the snow in a Gam-off? (Looking at the structure), or are they just meant for keeping the cold victim safe and warm while Evac is arranged?
- On a funnier part, Can that it be used as a shelter rather than bivouacking?

Comment: Gamow bags are not used to treat cold (hypothermia). They are used to treat AMS, a completely different condition, although the two are commonly found together.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These are emergency kit - specifically to help those suffering health problems due to altitude. As I understand it they are used within the climber's tent or bivouac, which provides the shelter required, and they provide an environment that matches a lower altitude, through pressurising the bag, allowing altitude sickness to be alleviated.

So, looking at your 5 points:

1. no. They are for use at altitude
2. not a good question for SE. I'd suggest editing it out - a web search comes up with suppliers who have a range of costs and specifications
3. there are different versions. [The one in the picture below](http://www.chinookmed.com/cgi-bin/item/06001/s-high_altitude/-Gamow-Bag-Hyperbaric-Chamber,-Civilian-Model-) weighs in at 12.7lb
4. They are not specifically for keeping the victim safe and warm - but yes, they are designed such that the victim can stay inside the bag until they are at a lower altitide.
5. No. It will shelter a victim, but should not be used as a replacement for shelter.

[image]

Comment: The victim goes inside the Gamow bag. Someone has to stay outside pumping it, 24/7 till the victim has recovered or been evacuated to lower altitude. Without the pumping circulating fresh air, the victim will use all teh oxygen and suffocate - so not really a great shelter.